# How to add Namespace and Declaration to the existing XML

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

how to add Namespace and Declaration to the existing xml.

My XML

```
 <Order>
      <child1></child1>
 </Order>
```

Expected

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
 <Order xmlns="http://a.com/a">
       <child1></child>
 </Order>
```

Comment: How are you reading the XML?  XmlDocument, XDocument, something else?

Comment: I am reading using XmlDocument

Comment: You have to clone every node/attribute with new namespace with your own code walking down the tree - you can't change namespace on existing nodes into new namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're only changing the element namespaces and ignoring any attributes, you can parse this using LINQ to XML and then change every element's qualified name:

```
var doc  = XDocument.Parse(xml);

XNamespace ns = "http://a.com/a";

foreach (var element in doc.Descendants())
{
    element.Name = ns + element.Name.LocalName;
}
```